# what's difference between XML Notepad and Java SE bundle for XML writing/editing?

Tags: xml, xmlwriter, xml-parsing

I am looking for a simple XML editor to start learning XML and then do some actual XML projects with. Before I download one, I would like to ask your opinions on which one you prefer as you all are all XML experts.  These are the two simple **free** ones I've been told that work well for a simple XML editor. **But does the Java SE bundle actually support XML editing however? It is not mentioned on their website but I have heard people still use the editor for XML writing.**
Thank you.

(1) http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html
Java SE bundle (just to use the editor for XML -- ** does this editor support XML editing?**

(2) XML Notepad 2007 
XML Notepad 2007 provides a simple intuitive user interface for browsing and editing XML documents.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&DisplayLang=en#AffinityDownloads
This one sounds great but don't know anyone who's used it. Small, simple, just for XML editing.

Comment: What actual features do you want? Most normal text editors have a good-enough syntax highlighting mode for XML. I certainly never use any specialised tool for writing XML files.

Comment: Thanks, @bobince. As I mentioned to Captain Giraffe below, I need an XML supported editor that will let me know if my format is incorrect, help with formatting or whatever else I may do incorrectly as I learn XML. I am a total novice. It can be quite tedious typing in XML into an editor that doesn't guide or support what you are writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Netbeans supports XML editing. Highligting, namespaces and code completion.

[image: Screenshot]

The Java SE bundle is usually not considered to include Netbeans.

Comment: Thank you @Captain Giraffe. I guess I don't know what Netbeans are then. Can you tell me what it is? I was told to go to http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html and download the simplest Java bundle which is the Java SE bundle and just use its editor for XML writing/editing. I don't know Java and won't be using it. I need an XML supported editor that will let me know if my format is incorrect, help with formatting or whatever else I may do incorrectly as I learn XML.  Would an xml writer that comes with python work since I already have python downloaded? Or is the Java XML editor better?

Comment: @nlper NetBeans is the editor itself. The Java SE bundle is an additional pack for developing Java applications. The php and c++ pack is pretty small too if you're only looking for the editor.

Comment: do the php and c++ pack bundles also include the xml editor? I see in http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html, that the php and c++ come with editors but will they also support xml editing? Or is it only the Java editor that will support xml? I guess that is a main concern of mine. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, @Captain Giraffe. Being a beginner, I was a little confused by your first answer above: "The Java SE bundle is usually not considered to include Netbeans." So just to be totally clear before downloading, are you saying that in this case, if I download the Java SE bundle from netbeans.org/downloads/index.html, I will get the netbeans XML editor, which is what I really need. It just seems that I can't download ONLY the netbeans XML editor. Is that correct, please? Thanks so much.